# Get .xlsx attachment from Gmail and update rows in already existing Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to Google AppScripts, and really struggling with achieving my end goal. The following code get's me very close, but I am wondering if anyone can please point me in a direction that enables me to do the following:

1. Extract .xlsx file from gmail that is received daily
2. Transfer the contents of the .xlsx file to an already existing Google sheet

Any advice would be hugely appreciated.

James

```
// GLOBALS
//Array of file extension which you would like to extract to Drive
var fileTypesToExtract = ['jpg', 'tif', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'svg'];
//Name of the folder in google drive i which files will be put
var folderName = 'GmailToDrive';
//Name of the label which will be applied after processing the mail message
var labelName = 'GmailToDrive';



function GmailToDrive(){
  //build query to search emails
  var query = '';
  //filename:jpg OR filename:tif OR filename:gif OR fileName:png OR filename:bmp OR filename:svg'; //'after:'+formattedDate+
  for(var i in fileTypesToExtract){
 query += (query === '' ?('filename:'+fileTypesToExtract[i]) : (' OR filename:'+fileTypesToExtract[i]));
  }
  query = 'in:inbox has:nouserlabels ' + query;
  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  var label = getGmailLabel_(labelName);
  var parentFolder;
  if(threads.length > 0){
    parentFolder = getFolder_(folderName);
  }
  var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  for(var i in threads){
    var mesgs = threads[i].getMessages();
 for(var j in mesgs){
      //get attachments
      var attachments = mesgs[j].getAttachments();
      for(var k in attachments){
        var attachment = attachments[k];
        var isDefinedType = checkIfDefinedType_(attachment);
     if(!isDefinedType) continue;
     var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
        var file = DriveApp.createFile(attachmentBlob);
        parentFolder.addFile(file);
        root.removeFile(file);
      }
 }
 threads[i].addLabel(label);
  }
}

//This function will get the parent folder in Google drive
function getFolder_(folderName){
  var folder;
  var fi = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  if(fi.hasNext()){
    folder = fi.next();
  }
  else{
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderName);
  }
  return folder;
}

//getDate n days back
// n must be integer
function getDateNDaysBack_(n){
  n = parseInt(n);
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - n);
  return Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy/MM/dd');
}

function getGmailLabel_(name){
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(name);
  if(!label){
 label = GmailApp.createLabel(name);
  }
  return label;
}

//this function will check for filextension type.
// and return boolean
function checkIfDefinedType_(attachment){
  var fileName = attachment.getName();
  var temp = fileName.split('.');
  var fileExtension = temp[temp.length-1].toLowerCase();
  if(fileTypesToExtract.indexOf(fileExtension) !== -1) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you point out at what point in your code you truggle? Do you get any error message? Do you have a specific question about how to change a certain request?

Answer (score 0):

That's the codes I'm using for getting attachments from gmail to existing spreadsheet.
By setting up time driven trigger.
In order to make this function run faster. set the label name and the thread limites

```
function attachfromGmail(attachmentname, destsheet_id, destsheetname, label_name, all_or_part) {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xasdawfes2342ke");
  const labels = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label_name).getThreads(0, 10);
  const threads = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(labels);
  const today_date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  var fileid_FromGmail = "";
  threads.forEach(threads => {
    threads.filter(messge => {
      if (Utilities.formatDate(messge.getDate(), "GMT-6", "MM/dd/yyyy") == today_date) {
        messge.getAttachments().filter(attachments => {
          if (attachments.getName() == attachmentname && messge.isUnread() === true) {
            messge.markRead();
            const blob = attachments.copyBlob();
            var file_FromGmail = Drive.Files.insert(
              { title: attachmentname, parents: [{ "id": folder.getId() }] },
              blob,
              { convert: true }
            );
            fileid_FromGmail = file_FromGmail.id;
          }
        })
      }
    })
  })
  const created_file = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileid_FromGmail);
  const values = created_file.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const destfiles_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destsheet_id).getSheetByName(destsheetname);
  if (all_or_part === 'all' && values != undefined) {
    destfiles_sheet.clear();
    destfiles_sheet.getRange(1, 1, created_file.getLastRow(), created_file.getLastColumn()).setValues(values);
  } else if (values.length === 1 && values.toString() != 'No Data Available' || values.length > 1) {
    values.shift()
    destfiles_sheet.getRange(destfiles_sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
  //delete created file
  DriveApp.getFileById(fileid_FromGmail).setTrashed(true);
}
```

It works well, but I'm trying to get a better way to do the job. Instead of insert a new file and delete.  I know we can use csv parse function to get the data. but I can not fix the leading 0 issue in the csv file.
Then I'm trying to use XML file to transfer data, still working on it.
I will update this post if I get a better solution.